# How to calculate the Least Common Multiple of the numbers 1 to 10?

Tags: ruby

As I'm a beginner Ruby developer. I wonder how more advanced Ruby developers would solve this issue. I'm looking here for the smallest number that is divided by numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.

*More formally this is defined as the Least Common Multiple of two or more integers, in this case the numbers 1 to 10.*

My current attempt:

```
max_divider = 10
nums = (1..max_divider).to_a
found_count = 0
x = 0
while found_count == 0
  x += 1
  nums.each do |num|
    if x % num == 0
      found_count += 1
    end
  end

  if found_count != max_divider
    found_count = 0
  end
end

p x #=> 2520
```

Comment: You should make it clear whether you code works or not.  If it works, I would suggest posting to https://codereview.stackexchange.com.  If it doesn't work, you should explain exactly why you think it does not work.

Comment: Since you asked how other developers would do it: Ruby developers almost always indent with two spaces.

Comment: I disagree with whoever voted to close this question as "too broad".  It's really quite narrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
MAX_DIVIDER = 10
DIVIDERS = (1..MAX_DIVIDER)

number = MAX_DIVIDER
number += 1 until DIVIDERS.all? { |divider| number % divider == 0 }
number #=> 2520
```

You can also use `lcm` method [Integer#lcm](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-lcm) that will help you find the least common multiple.

```
DIVIDERS.reduce(:lcm) #=> 2520
```

Comment: `Range` mixes in `Enumerable`, there's no need to convert it to an `Array`. Just `(1..10).reduce(:lcm) #=> 2520` is enough.

Comment: The same thing applies to `any?`, actually, that's also an `Enumerable` method.

Comment: Your loop should be a one-liner:  `number += 1 until DIVIDERS.all? { |divider| number % divider == 0 }`